# Implementation of lockf() for android NDK

Tags: android, file, locking, android-ndk, cups

The Android NDK lacks the lockf() function.
While I was compiling CUPS with Android NDK, the error came of missing lockf().
Hence there is need to create function similar to lockf() for NDK.
Please help me in creating such a function.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

PS:I m a noob

Answer (score 1):

This is how another Google produce handles it

```
// The lockf() function is not available on Android; we translate to flock().
#define F_LOCK LOCK_EX
#define F_ULOCK LOCK_UN
inline int lockf(int fd, int cmd, off_t ignored_len) {
    return flock(fd, cmd);
}
```

https://src.chromium.org/svn/branches/1312/src/base/os_compat_android.h

Answer (score 0):

Even if you implement the lockf() you'll still have some problems using it, because Android has a restricted permission management. Generally two processes won't both have read/write permission on a same directory.  I mean, you have no directory to place this file to be locked.